# click link in textview

Tags: android

I have text view and I want to set-text as link to direct the site but 
the problem is that I cannot click:

```
                    Grades = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
                    Grades.setText(Html.fromHtml(course.getString(TAG_Grade)));

                Grades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        WebView webView; webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
                        {

                        }webView.loadUrl(course.getString(TAG_Grade)); });
```

And the xml:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="365dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:onClick="onClick"
/>
```

Knowing that `course.getString(TAG_Grade)` will get the url from db but it does not work

What is the problem?

Comment: Try adding android:clickable="true" property to textview in xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to Linkify it *after* the view is clicked, removed the Linkify from within the onClick.

---

Your going about it the wrong way.

Try this:

```
String userCanSeeThis = "Your Website Name";
String url = course.getString(TAG_Grade);

TextView grades = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
grades.setText(userCanSeeThis);

addLinks(Grades, userCanSeeThis, url);
```

Using this helper method:

```
    /**
     * @param textView
     *            textView who's text you want to change
     * @param linkThis
     *            a regex of what text to turn into a link
     * @param toThis
     *            the url you want to send them to
     */
    public static void addLinks(TextView textView, String linkThis, String toThis) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(linkThis);
        String scheme = toThis;
        android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern, scheme, new MatchFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
                return true;
            }
        }, new TransformFilter() {

            @Override
            public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
                return "";
            }
        });
    }
```

Also if you set the `onClickListener` in your code with `grades.setOnClickListener` then your don't need `android:onClick=""` in your XML

Comment: @MaramWatban yes , you don't need click listeners if you use Linkify

Comment: and even the  android:clickable="true" ?

Comment: @MaramWatban yep not needed either

Comment: her is some problem that happend how can i solve it http://store3.up-00.com/Nov12/kBb01972.png

Comment: @MaramWatban I can't see your code, but you have a syntax error, like a missing bracket or semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

Used this `android:clickable="true"`

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="365dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:autoLink="web"
     android:onClick="onClick"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Linkify` i would prefer the below line:

```
 Html.fromHtml(course.getString(TAG_Grade));
```

Comment: you mean like this    Grades.setText(course.getString(TAG_Grade));
 
     Grades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
        Html.fromHtml(course.getString(TAG_Grade));
       Grades.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
      }
     });

Comment: No. Like this: Grades.setText(Html.fromHtml(course.getString(TAG_Grade)));Grades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { //Do whatever you want to do here: });

Comment: i want after the clcik the link it go to the site what should i do in th onclick

Comment: Place this method in OnClick: WebView webView; webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        webView.loadUrl(course.getString(TAG_Grade))
    });

Comment: the code have problem with some ")" is missing but i do not know what ?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView myWebSite = new TextView(this);
myWebSite .setText("http://www.google.com/");
Linkify.addLinks(myWebSite , Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have received enough answers regarding Linkify, but there is one more subtile error crawling in your code:

You are mistaking the attribute his `android:onClick` with the method `onClick` of an `View.onClickListener`:

The attribute `android:onClick` works as followed:

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is
>   clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes
>   exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify
>   android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void
>   sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

As for the `onClick`-method provided by the `View.onClickListener`-interface:

```
view.setOnClickListener(...)
```

> Register a callback to be invoked when this view is
>   clicked. If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.

Which will allow you to override the function :

```
public abstract void onClick (View v)
```

which is called when a view has been clicked.